# Accessing an Outlook Add-in via redemption

Tags: outlook, office-addins, office-automation, outlook-redemption

Is is possible to access an outlook add-in via redemption, rather than me adding the add-in  to my application, I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: Are you trying to do something with a a third-party addin?

Answer (score 0):

Redemption is a wrapper around Extended MAPI, not Outlook. So, it doesn't provide anything for dealing with Outlook features like add-ins.

You can get the Outlook running instance or create a new one of none exists and then access the COM add-ins list. The [COMAddIns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.comaddins) property of the `Application` class returns a `COMAddIns` collection that represents all the Component Object Model (COM) add-ins currently loaded in Microsoft Outlook.

```
Private Sub CountCOMAddins() 
 MsgBox "There are " & Application.COMAddIns.Count & " COM add-ins." 
End Sub
```